# AdapterView item not filling parent

Tags: android, layout

I create class A that extends "AdapterView<ListAdapter>", and create class D that extends "BaseAdapter" providing the data.

The problem is that every AdapterView item is not stretching its length to AdapterView's length, and the length of each item is different as it is the same as the length of the text in the item. I set all layout parameters I can set to "FILL_PARENT", but that does not make sense.

Which class should I check? The AdapterView subclass, or the BaseAdapter subclass, or the TextView subclass in AdapterView item? (I subclass TextView to get some extra effect).

The getView methods:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.colselector_menu_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        TextView tv = new VerticalTextView(viewGroup.getContext());
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        NewsInTimeApp app = (NewsInTimeApp) (((MainActivity) context)
                .getApplication());
        tv.setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(app.getConfig().get(
                AppConfig.CFGNAME_UI_MAIN_COLSELECTOR_TEXTSIZE)));
        ((LinearLayout) convertView).addView(tv);
        holder.groupItem = tv;

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.groupItem.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.collId = list.get(position).getId();

    return convertView;
}
```

The colselector_menu_item.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#e1e1e1"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check all of them. Showing code for them would help too.

Comment: @Geobits There are 3 class and 3 layout xml to show at least, seems too messy. I uploaded the snapshot: http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/606/9120120911103900.png The view in blue color is the AdapterView which is inside a popup, and the view in light gray color is the AdapterView item. You can see that the height of AdapterView is bigger than that of any item.

Comment: Right, but what you're getting is *the* definition of "wrap_content", so something isn't being set right. Check all the layouts, and especially check anywhere in your code that inflates them. At a minimum, paste the code from your Adapter's `getView` method. Anywhere you're setting parameters or inflating views could be the culprit, but without seeing any code at all, it's going to be impossible to narrow it down.

Comment: @Geobits Yes, I think there maybe some "wrap_content" but as I've said, I've changed all I can set to "FILL_PARENT". The getView method is pasted above which I guess may be the cause of the problem. Also there is the layout xml of the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding the view, you're not specifying any layout parameters for the TextView itself.

Try:

```
(LinearLayout) convertView.addView(tv, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

If targeting API<8, change MATCH_PARENT to FILL_PARENT. This also assumes you do want them to wrap content vertically.

Comment: Greate, that works! BTW, my textview is a vertical textview so the parameter I use in addView method is actually "tv, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT". And there's a small question --- as the 1px view in the xml I shown is already set to "fill_parent", why I need to set the textview to "fill_parent" too?

Comment: because you are shwing data in run time show you have to add run time otherwise you can't able to show data in fill_parent. @realjin